# Omission a part of sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, style

I wrote this sentence:

> The resulting rulesets are organized in a hierarchical fashion to make it possible to share the rules for extracting content from similar websites.

Can I remove part of it and write it as

> The resulting rulesets are organized in a hierarchical fashion to make it possible to share the rules for  <s>extracting content from</s>  similar websites.

These omission may change the meaning of the sentence without any context, but in both I mean extracting content from similar websites, can I rely context to do such changes?!

---

**Update:** If I use "reuse" instead of "share" I can write it as:

> The resulting rulesets are organized in a hierarchical fashion to make it possible to reuse the rules for similar websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word '*reuse*' works a bit better than '*share*', IMO, especially if you consider that the more common preposition used with the verb '*share*' is "*among*" (or "*between*" if only two entities share something) and "*with*".

Yes, if the context of the sentence already establishes that you are talking about [rules for] *extracting content[s]* from websites, no need to repeat it.